# How to return physical pages while keeping virtual addresses mapped?

Tags: linux, mmap

I'd like to reserve a large contiguous region (4GiB) of virtual address space. I can do this with `mmap`. Then, as I write to the memory, the kernel will gradually cause it to become physically backed. At some stage I'd like to *return* physical pages within this range back to the kernel, while keeping the entire region of virtual address space still mapped. My issue is that if I return physical pages with `munmap`, then I not only return the physical pages, but I also return the virtual address space.

Is it possible to return just the physical pages while still keeping the virtual address space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, call [madvise(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) with `advice` set to `MADV_DONTNEED`.